# Proving that a particular function belongs to a sheaf of functions

Tags: differential-topology, sheaf-theory, smooth-manifolds

I have the following exercise

> Let $M,N$ be open subsets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $\Psi:M\to N$ be a smooth map. Show that $\Psi$ defines a morphism of spaces ringed by smooth functions.

The definitions are the following:

> A **presheaf** $\mathcal{F}$ of functions on a topological space $M$ is a collection of subrings $\mathcal{F}(U)\subset C(U)$ of the ring $C(U)$ of all functions on $U$, for each open subset $U\subset M$, such that the restriction of every $\gamma\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ to an open subset $U_{1}\subset U$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}(U_{1})$.
>
> A **sheaf** $\mathcal{F}$ of functions on a topological space $M$ is a presheaf on $M$ such that the following condition is met. Let $\{U_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover (possibly infinite) of an open subset $U\subset M$ and $f_{i}\in\mathcal{F}(U_{i})$ a family of functions defined on the open sets of the cover, compatible on the pairwise intersections: $$f_{i}\left.\right\vert_{U_{i}\cap U_{j}}=f_{j}\left.\right\vert_{U_{i}\cap U_{j}} $$
>   for every pair $(U_{i},U_{j})$ of members of the cover. Then, there exists $f\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $f_{i}$ is the restriction of $f$ to $U_{i}$ for all $i\in I$.
>
> A **ringed space** $(M,\mathcal{F})$ is a a topological space equipped with a sheaf of functions.
>
> A **morphism** $(M,\mathcal{F}_{M})\stackrel{\Psi}{\longrightarrow}(N,\mathcal{F}_{N})$ of ringed spaces is a continuous map such that, for every open subset $U\subset N$ and every function $f\in\mathcal{F}_{N}$, the function $f\circ\Psi$ belongs to the ring $\mathcal{F}_{M}(\Psi^{-1}(U))$.

I do not understand how to proof that a particular function (here, $f\circ\Psi$) belongs to some ring. Here, it is clear that $f\circ\Psi$ is smooth, as the composite of smooth functions. But what other conditions do I have to show? What does that mean to "belong to the ring $\mathcal{F}_{M}(\Psi^{-1}(U))$"?

The ring $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is equipped with which operations? I suppose they are usual addition and multiplication of functions. But I guess this exercise is not only about showing that $f\circ\psi^{-1}+g$ and $(f\circ\psi^{-1})\cdot g$ are both smooth functions in $\mathcal{F}_{M}(\Psi^{-1}(U))$ for any $g\in\mathcal{F}_{M}(\Psi^{-1}(U))$ for all open $U\subset N$.

To summarize my question: what do I need to show?

Comment: you guess right

Comment: @Moebius Corzer: $"f\circ\psi^{-1}+g, (f\circ\psi^{-1})\cdot g$ are smooth functions on $\Psi^ {-1}(U)$ not  $\mathcal{F}_{M}(\Psi^{-1}(U))$!

Comment: @Babai Of course it's a typo. But thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Are you able to do the exercise?

Comment: You can see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527302/psi-is-a-morphism-of-ringed-spaces-iff-it-is-smooth-in-local-coordinates/1656809#1656809